# Defining colours in combined map

Tags: r, ggplot2, bubble-chart, choropleth

At the moment I'm working on a combined map in which on the one hand choropleths will be shown and on the other hand bubbles will be added.
For the most part, I manage to do this, but there are problems with the color design.
I can only determine the colour of the bubbles within the `geom_point` function. However, as soon as I want to take the bubble shape with an outline colour and use the *fill* argument within `aes()`, the colours of the choropleths, which are defined in `scale_fill_manual`, are used.

Hence my question: Is it possible to use a second `scale_fill` argument for the bubble colour?
Or how can I change the legend so that the extra value that defines the bubble color is not added to the choropleth values?

Here is an example for better understanding:

```
#load data
lapply(c("rgdal","ggplot2","broom"),require,character.only=TRUE)
URL<-"https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/distribution/v2/nuts/download/ref-nuts-2016-10m.shp.zip"
fil<-basename(URL)
if(!file.exists(fil))download.file(URL,fil)
fils<-unzip(fil)
shp<-grep("shp$",fils,value=TRUE)[4]
lay<-ogrListLayers(shp)[1]
de<-readOGR(shp,lay)
de<-de[de$CNTR_CODE=="DE",]
de.df<-tidy(de,region="NUTS_ID")

#choropleth data
values<-data.frame(group=unique(de.df$group),
                   emp=runif(length(unique(de.df$group)),1,100))
de.df<-merge(de.df,values,by="group")
de.df$emp_c<-cut(de.df$emp,breaks=c(seq(0,100,by=20)))

#point/bubble data
nuts_centr<-coordinates(de)
proj<-data.frame(group=de$NUTS_ID,
                 long=nuts_centr[,1],
                 lat=nuts_centr[,2],
                 size=runif(length(unique(de$NUTS_ID)),1,100))

#colours
col<-colorRampPalette(c("#fff7fb","#014636"))
```

This is the plot where the bubble colour is determined within the given colour palette of the choroplets and the legend is accordingly wrong:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=de.df,
               aes(long,lat,group=group,fill=emp_c),
               alpha=0.75,colour="gray",lwd=0.1) +
  geom_point(data=proj, 
             aes(long,lat,size=size,fill="#ef6548"),
             colour="black",pch=21,alpha=.75) +
  scale_size_continuous(name="Employment",range=c(1,8)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Projects",values=col(7)) +
  theme(line=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_blank()) +
  coord_equal()
```

Resulting in:

[image: Map I]

This is what it should look like, apart from the missing outline colour of the bubbles:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=de.df,
               aes(long,lat,group=group,fill=emp_c),
               alpha=0.75,colour="gray",lwd=0.1) +
  geom_point(data=proj,
             aes(long,lat,size=size),
             colour="#ef6548",alpha=.75) +
  scale_size_continuous(name="Employment",range=c(1,8)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Projects",values=col(6)) +
  theme(line=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_blank()) +
  coord_equal()
```

Resulting in:

[image: Map II]

As a novice with geodata and with R I am grateful for any tips, also in other areas, which may have been written inefficiently.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you want to avoid an entry appearing in a legend, include `guide = FALSE` in the `scale_fill` call. If you want to make dots appear to be outlined in one colour but filled with another, try plotting a smaller dot on top of a larger one, see the [ggplot reference pages](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_point.html)

Comment: Hi @EcologyTom, thank you very much for welcoming me and for the quick tips! The problem with the legend is that I only want to delete one element, not the entire legend.
The solution with the second layer works already quite well and will be sufficient in case of doubt, but thereby I take the possibility to determine an _alpha_ in a meaningful way.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem completely. But does moving `fill="#ef6548"` out of `aes()` in your first plot work? It sounds like you want to specify both the fill & colour for your bubbles, rather than involve them in any aesthetic mapping.

Comment: Thank you @Z.Lin! That worked. I really missed the most obvious.